# boost::bind together with boost::asio. boost::bind not working, copied from an example

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

Could someone tell me why this does not compile? I basically copied it from an example by Kholkoff (http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2007/04/120339.php), back in 2007, about reads() in sockets with timeouts:

```
void CClient::setResult(boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*
                         a,boost::system::error_code b)
{
    *a = b;
}
```

I'm binding() it like this:

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CClient::setResult, &timer_result, _1));
```

The errors that gcc prints are unreadable to me:

```
static assertion failed: WaitHandler type requirements not met  remote_server       line 499, external location: /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp   C/C++ Problem
no match for call to ‘(boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (CClient::*)(boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*, boost::system::error_code), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>, boost::arg<1> > >) (const boost::system::error_code&)’  remote_server       line 499, external location: /usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp   C/C++ Problem
‘void (CClient::*)(boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*, boost::system::error_code)’ is not a class, struct, or union type   remote_server       line 69, external location: /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp    C/C++ Problem
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.             C/C++ Problem
make: *** [src/CClient.o] Error 1   remote_server           C/C++ Problem
  required from ‘class boost::_bi::bind_t<boost::_bi::unspecified, void (CClient::*)(boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*, boost::system::error_code), boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>, boost::arg<1> > >’  remote_server       line 15, external location: /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp   C/C++ Problem
  required from here    CClient.cpp /remote_server/src  line 93 C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: Please format your error output as you would your code with the indent of four spaces.  This is taking hard to read output and making it worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

And how about

```
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CClient::setResult, this, &timer_result, _1));
```

`setResult` is member function, if you use `async_wait` in `CClient`, or use some object of type `CClient` instead of `this`.

Comment: In this case it is worth to say that `this` must be of type `CClient`.