# boost::bind together with boost::asio. boost::bind follow up

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio, boost-bind

Now I'd like to add two parameters to the function of the former question: [boost::bind together with boost::asio. boost::bind not working, copied from an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12364625/boostbind-together-with-boostasio-boostbind-not-working-copied-from-an-e)

**EDIT:** Sorry, forgot to add the type of timer_result:    boost::optional timer_result;

```
//my function
void CClient::setResult2(boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>* a, boost::system::error_code b,
const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t);

//my attempt: I'd like to set the value of the first, third and fourth parameters but not the second one
timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CClient::setResult2, this, &timer_result, _1,boost::asio::placeholders::error,
              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
```

Does the _1 mean something different from the last question? Thanks.

**Errors:**

```
Description     Resource        Path    Location        Type  
required from ‘void boost::asio::basic_deadline_timer<Time,
TimeTraits, TimerService>::async_wait(WaitHandler&&) [with WaitHandler
= boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient, boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >; Time =
boost::posix_time::ptime; TimeTraits =
boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>; TimerService =
boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<boost::posix_time::ptime,
boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> >]’   remote_server
line 501, external location:
/usr/include/boost/asio/basic_deadline_timer.hpp   C/C++ Problem
invalid user-defined conversion from ‘const boost::system::error_code’
to ‘unsigned int’ [-fpermissive] remote_server           line 525,
external location: /usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp   C/C++ Problem  
required from ‘void boost::_bi::list5<A1, A2, A3, A4,
A5>::operator()(boost::_bi::type<void>, F&, A&, int) [with F =
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>; A = boost::_bi::list1<const boost::system::error_code&>; A1 =
boost::_bi::value<CClient*>; A2 =
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>; A3 =
boost::arg<1>; A4 = boost::arg<1> (*)(); A5 = boost::arg<2> (*)()]’   
remote_server           line 525, external location:
/usr/include/boost/bind/bind.hpp   C/C++ Problem size of array is
negative       remote_server           line 37, external location:
/usr/include/boost/bind/arg.hpp     C/C++ Problem make: ***
[src/CClient.o] Error 1       remote_server                   C/C++
Problem   required from ‘void boost::asio::detail::binder1<Handler,
Arg1>::operator()() [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >; Arg1 =
boost::system::error_code]’     remote_server           line 46,
external location: /usr/include/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp    
C/C++ Problem   required from ‘boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F,
L>::result_type boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::operator()(const A1&)
[with A1 = boost::system::error_code; R = void; F =
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>; L = boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()>;
boost::_bi::bind_t<R, F, L>::result_type = void]’    remote_server    
line 47, external location: /usr/include/boost/bind/bind_template.hpp 
C/C++ Problem   required from ‘void
boost_asio_handler_invoke_helpers::invoke(Function&, Context&) [with
Function = boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >,
boost::system::error_code>; Context = boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >]’
remote_server           line 39, external location:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/handler_invoke_helpers.hpp   C/C++
Problem   required from ‘void
boost::asio::asio_handler_invoke(Function, ...) [with Function =
boost::asio::detail::binder1<boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >,
boost::system::error_code>]’       remote_server           line 64,
external location: /usr/include/boost/asio/handler_invoke_hook.hpp    
C/C++ Problem   required from
‘boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>::wait_handler(Handler&)
[with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf4<void,
CClient, boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >]’  
remote_server           line 39, external location:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp     C/C++ Problem  
required from ‘static void
boost::asio::detail::wait_handler<Handler>::do_complete(boost::asio::detail::io_service_impl*,
boost::asio::detail::operation*, const boost::system::error_code&,
std::size_t) [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >;
boost::asio::detail::io_service_impl =
boost::asio::detail::task_io_service; boost::asio::detail::operation =
boost::asio::detail::task_io_service_operation; std::size_t = unsigned
int]’ remote_server           line 69, external location:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/wait_handler.hpp     C/C++ Problem
make: *** No rule to make target `all'.                         C/C++
Problem   required from ‘void
boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType,
TimeTraits>::async_wait(boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType,
TimeTraits>::implementation_type&, WaitHandler&&) [with WaitHandler =
boost::_bi::bind_t<void, boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >; TimeType =
boost::posix_time::ptime; TimeTraits =
boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>;
boost::asio::deadline_timer_service<TimeType,
TimeTraits>::implementation_type =
boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>
>::implementation_type]’ remote_server           line 138, external location: /usr/include/boost/asio/deadline_timer_service.hpp C/C++
Problem   required from ‘void
boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::async_wait(boost::asio::detail::deadline_timer_service<Time_Traits>::implementation_type&,
Handler) [with Handler = boost::_bi::bind_t<void,
boost::_mfi::mf4<void, CClient,
boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*,
boost::system::error_code, const boost::system::error_code&, unsigned
int>, boost::_bi::list5<boost::_bi::value<CClient*>,
boost::_bi::value<boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>*>,
boost::arg<1>, boost::arg<1> (*)(), boost::arg<2> (*)()> >;
Time_Traits = boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime>]’
remote_server           line 180, external location:
/usr/include/boost/asio/detail/deadline_timer_service.hpp  C/C++
Problem   required from here    CClient.cpp     /remote_server/src    
line 102        C/C++ Problem
```

**Infos:**

```
Description     Resource        Path    Location        Type candidate is: 
boost::system::error_code::operator boost::system::error_code::unspecified_bool_type() const <near match>
remote_server           line 355, external location:
/usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp   C/C++ Problem   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘boost::system::error_code::unspecified_bool_type {aka void (*)()}’ to ‘unsigned int’      remote_server           line 355, external
location: /usr/include/boost/system/error_code.hpp   C/C++ Problem
```

Comment: Sorry khomyakoshka, I think I undid your much appreciated edit...

Answer (score 0):

You have two error codes in your method and only one error placeholder inside bind.

Answer (score 0):

`placeholders::error` is an alias for `_1`, and `placeholders::bytes_transferred` is actually `_2`, so you can't put `_1` again.

Move your additional argument to be the third one: `void CClient::setResult2(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t, boost::optional<boost::system::error_code>* a)` and pass `&timer_result` as a third parameter. Like this:

`bind(&CClient::setResult2, this, _1, _2, &timer_result)`.

(I used short placeholders here, but you can substitute them with the longer asio ones, if you like them.)

Comment: Sorry. How should my timer.async_wait(boost::bind(&CClient::setResult2, this, &timer_result, _1,boost::asio::placeholders::error,
              boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
call look? I tried a couple of things but those didn't work.

Comment: @user1613 I've updated my answer, please see it again. By the way, I don't quite understand what `boost::system::error_code b` is. It seems superfluous, so I omited it.

Answer (score 0):

`async_wait()` accepts a function with this signature (from the Boost.ASIO docs):

```
void handler(
  const boost::system::error_code& error // Result of operation.
);
```

Your bind results in a function-ish thing with a signature resembling:

```
void bound_setResult2(_1, _error, _bytes_transferred);
```

Each placeholder in the bind() call maps to a parameter in the bind result.  You have three placeholders. Of course it doesn't compile. But you have a bigger, conceptual problem.

You seem to think that the deadline timer knows about the I/O underway.  It does not.  The handler just gets called when the timer elapses, or is canceled. (And the error code indicates whether it was canceled.) The timer handler should not be expected to to know about #bytes transferred.  It's up to your I/O handler (not the timer-expired handler) to keep track of that info.

Probably, all you really want in your timer handler is code that calls  `port.cancel()` and then, in `setResults2()` -- which should be the handler for the I/O, not for the timer -- you deal with the cancellation.